# How to get current page name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, yoast

I want to put the Current page title in wordpress but unable to get the page name, i have tried to use following into my header.php

```
<?php 
wp_title(" ");
?>
```

But it is displaying as: 
**`"Blog Name - Current Page title "`**
this problem is coming when i using yoast plugin in my website, if i am deactivating the plugin then current page title is displaying perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$page_name = $wp_query->post->post_title;

Answer (score 1):

This would print the title to the screen.

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

---

For more customized and advancement you can use below:

```
function the_title( $before = '', $after = '', $echo = true ) {
    $title = get_the_title();

    if ( strlen( $title ) == 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    $title = $before . $title . $after;
```

Comment: i have tried but not get the desired result. Thanks

Comment: can you give more precision @ManishAgarwal? This solution should answer your question.

Comment: @ManishAgarwal this is only and 100% sure solution. Can you explain your issue better

Comment: i have tried with the_title(); function from codex, and its solved my issue for now.